# CQL not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql

I tried to execute an insert statement using `CQL` in `Python`.

The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.test_table (
key1 text PRIMARY KEY,
key2 text,
key3 int,
key4 float,
key5 float
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

The Python code is:

```
no_of_rows = 10000

insert_test_pre_stm = "INSERT INTO test_table (key1, key2, key3, key4, key5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"


for row in range(no_of_rows):
    key = 'test' + str(row)
    session.execute(insert_test_pre_stm, [key, 'test', 1900, 1.0, 1.0])
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

UPDATE

I have solved the problem, which is due to not using prepared statements(`session.prepare`).

Comment: I think you should add the solution as an answer. I almost missed it. Thank you though, I was loosing my mind. :D